# generating unique row and column in 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am randomly filling a 2 dimensional array but i want to have the numbers generated in each row and column to be unique. Here is the code i have used

```
int[][] values = new int[3][3];

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

        int[] sub = values[i];
        for (int x = 0; x < sub.length; x++) {
            sub[x]= randomGenerator.nextInt(4);;
        System.out.print(sub[x] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

My current output is and this might change as the numbers generated are random

```
2 2 2 
3 2 0 
0 2 1
```

But i am expecting something like this

```
1 2 3 
3 1 2 
2 3 1
```

Comment: This output looks like what I would expect from this code. It is pure (pseudo)random...

Comment: I know, i want to put some conditions to it so that i can regenerate it incase there is duplication in the row or column.

Comment: @AND what is the biggest possible 2D array size you will use? Only 3 x 3?

Comment: I am planning 9 x 9 and planning to randomly generate numbers from 1 to 9.

Comment: @AND Good news to you, I just tried coding it with brute force approach, it took less than **1 sec** to generate 9x9 unique matrix. Let me know if you want me to post my codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this problem with the brute force approach and it works.
It took less than **1 sec** to generate a unique 9 x 9 board.

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
2 6 8 9 7 4 1 3 5 
6 3 5 7 9 1 2 4 8 
9 5 4 8 6 2 3 1 7 
5 4 7 1 2 8 9 6 3 
8 1 9 6 3 7 5 2 4 
4 9 2 3 8 5 6 7 1 
7 8 6 5 1 3 4 9 2 
3 7 1 2 4 9 8 5 6
```

Below is my codes:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int size = 9;

    int[][] board= new int[size][size];
    board[0] = Util.createOrderedArray(size, 1);

    for(int x=1; x<size; x++){          
        board[x] = Util.createOrderedArray(size, 1);
        do{
            Util.shuffle(board[x]);
        }while(!Util.compare2DArray(board[x], board, 0, x));        
    }       
    Util.print(board);  
}
```

I wrote all my helper methods inside a self-defined Util class.

```
final class Util
{
    public static void shuffle(int[] num){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for(int x=0; x<num.length; x++)
            swap(num, x, rnd.nextInt(num.length));
    }

    public static void swap(int[] num, int a, int b){
        int temp = num[a];
        num[a] = num[b];
        num[b] = temp;
    }

    public static int[] createOrderedArray(int size, int startValue){
        int[] num = new int[size];
        for(int x=0; x<num.length; x++)
            num[x] = x+startValue;      
        return num;
    }

    //Return TRUE if array vs arrays is COMPLETELY different
    public static boolean compare2DArray(int[] num1, int[][] num2, int start, int end){
        for(int x=start; x<end; x++)
            if(!compareArray(num1, num2[x]))
                return false;
        return true;        
    }

    //Return TRUE if arrays are COMPLETELY different 
    public static boolean compareArray(int[] num1, int[] num2){
        if(num1.length != num2.length)
            return false;
        for(int x=0; x<num1.length; x++)
            if(num1[x] == num2[x])
                return false;
        return true;        
    }

    public static void print(int[][] num){
        for(int x=0; x<num.length; x++){
            for(int y=0; y<num[0].length; y++)
                System.out.print(num[x][y] + " ");
            System.out.println(""); 
        }                           
    }
}
```

This is done by the brute force approach. If you want to do it elegantly, it will be more efficient if we do it recursively, so there are no unnecessary loopings wasted.

Comment: **Remarks:** The Util class I created is flexible. You can do a `Util.shuffle(board[0]);` so that the first row is no longer ordered. You can also create matrix of different sizes. However, a matrix with size more than 10 can take longer time to process.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me you are trying to create a matrix similar to a Sudoku board except you didn't ask to check each individual 3x3 sub-matrix.

If you are planning for 9x9 matrix. It is unlikely you can use random for all 81 elements. (You can, but it may take much longer than needed to generate the board).

This is what you can do:

- Create 2 arrays for tracking whether the current row/column already has 1-9
- Create a set of numbers to pick from (number range follows matrix size)
- Fill the first row with 1-9 randomly.
- Recursively populate the empty boxes with numbers by checking whether it can be filled.
- As you fill a number, remove it from the set of numbers
- If there is conflict, backtrack to last known good position and continue

Answer (score 0):

here is one way of doing it.

you can keep a track of what numbers have been generated, and ignore them if they are generated again.

I use `Set` as it disallows duplicate values. but I believe any other Collections should do the trick.

```
int[][] values = new int[3][3];

Random randomGenerator = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    Set<Integer> set= new HashSet<Integer>();
    int[] sub = values[i];
    for (int x = 0; x < sub.length;) {
        int next= randomGenerator.nextInt(4) + 1;// +1 ensure a number in {1,2,3}

        if(!set.contains){
          sub[x]= next;
          set.add(next);
          x++;  //note we only add the variable if non-duplicate values were generated.
          System.out.print(sub[x] + " ");
        }

    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**NOTE,**

if you try to change the size of your array, its better to change

```
int next= randomGenerator.nextInt(4) + 1;
```

to

```
int next= randomGenerator.nextInt(values[i].length) + 1;
```

so it ensures that you always have enough `distinct` numbers to generate

Comment: I think something must follow "set.contains". We are expected to but object after it

Comment: @AND sorry, I forgot to add `!` before it( so if it `doesn't` contain). I've eddited the answer, ty

Comment: @nafas I think this solution has a potential problem. When row1 has `1,2,3`, how to you prevent row2 from becoming `2,1,3` ?

Comment: @user3437460 look at the desired output mate, row2 can indeed become `2,1,3`

Comment: @nafas If row1 is `1,2,3` and row2 is `2,1,3`. The last column is no longer unique. `3` is repeating in last column.